# WPF Binding textbox to listview stops after textbox value is updated

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I have a listview that when selected, will populate data from the selected lineitem into separate textboxes.

I used databinding to accomplish the task, which seems to work fine:

```
<TextBox x:Name="SKU_TxtBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,21,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.SKU, ElementName=Inventory_ListView, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The above code works correctly. The problem starts if in the codebehind I have to change the textbox value; afterwards the databinding stops.

```
SKU_TxtBox.text = ""
```

After the above line runs, the textbox will remain blank no matter what is selected in the listview.

Comment: You are removing the binding from the text property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with bindings, you should always manipulate **only** the binding source.

```
Inventory_ListView.SelectedItem.SKU = ""
```

Or a better approach is to have a **View Model** bound to the view. in which you define a `Dependency Property` (currentSKU). Then bind it to both `Inventory_ListView.SelectedItem` and `SKU_TxtBox.text`. Then it will be:

```
CurrentSKU = ""
```